# Make c3p0 behave like Hibernate built-in connection pool

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

Probably this is stupid or weird question but I'm facing a strange bug in the app for many weeks and do not know how to solve it.

There are some Quartz jobs that periodically updating database (change the status of orders and stuff). There is only Hibernate 3.1.3 without spring and all transactions handled in code manually with explicit call session.close() in finally block.

It all worked fine with Hibernate built-in connection pool, however after I have changed built-in connection pool to c3p0 pool there are some bugs appeared connected with database transaction/session management. There is no exceptions or anything in the log files, so it is hard to tell what exactly was the reason.

Is there any way to make c3p0 connection pool behave like built-in pool by configuration? I need only one c3p0 feature - checking dead connections. Before this pool was implemented there was idle SQL Connection Reset issue. To keep connections alive I decided to use c3p0 pooling instead of built-in.

here is my current c3p0 configuration:

```
c3p0.min_size=0
c3p0.max_size=100
c3p0.max_statements=0
c3p0.idle_test_period=600
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=select 1 from dual
c3p0.autoCommitOnClose=true
c3p0.checkoutTimeout=120000
c3p0.acquireIncrement=2
c3p0.privilegeSpawnedThreads=true
c3p0.numHelperThreads=8
```

Thanks in advance.

c3p0 is an old version: 0.9.0.4, because I have Java 1.4 environment.

Here is a rough example how transactions are managed by the code:

```
SessionFactory  sessionFactory  = null;
Context         ctx             = null;
Object          obj             = null;

ctx             = new InitialContext();
obj             = ctx.lookup("HibernateSessionFactory");
sessionFactory  = (SessionFactory) obj;
session         = sessionFactory.openSession();

Transaction tx = null;

try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    // some transactional code

    if (!tx.wasRolledBack() && !tx.wasCommitted()) {
        tx.commit();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (tx != null && !tx.wasRolledBack() && !tx.wasCommitted()) {
        // if it is runtime exception then rollback
        if (ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, "10001", ex);
                try {
                    tx.rollback();
                } catch (RuntimeException rtex) {
                    logger.log(Level.ERROR, "10002", rtex);
                }   
    }
    else {
         // attempt to commit if there are any other exceptions
         try {
             tx.commit();
         } catch (RuntimeException rtex) {
             logger.log(Level.ERROR, "10004", rtex);

             // if commit fails then try to rollback
             try {
                 tx.rollback();
             } catch (RuntimeException rtex2) {
                 logger.log(Level.ERROR, "10002", rtex2);
             }
                 // then rethrow this exception
                 throw rtex;
         }
    }
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: Could you send the code that opens and closes the transactions? I believe your problem is that you do not call `commit()` or something like this. It worked with previous implementation because default auto-commit behavior.

Comment: setting c3p0.autoCommitOnClose to true is IMHO a very bad idea unless you have a very good reason. [ see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#autoCommitOnClose ] since you are not seeing exceptions (and have not described what you mean by "bugs...connected with database transaction/session management), one possibility is that you are occasionally commit()ing transactions that ought not to be committed, corrupting your database. otherwise, you'll need to give a better description of what's going wrong before i'll be able to help. btw, what version of c3p0 are you using?

Comment: I have tried with default autoCommitOnClose = false as well. The same issue persists. I have updated the post with version details and transnational code samples.

Comment: By the way what about c3p0 connection customizer? Can I configure it so it would work like built-in mechanism?